# WooCommerce - different icons for product categories

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have difficulties with changing icons of product categories in my sidebar widget. I was browsing many forums but i couldnt find any good answer for this.
[image]

This is sidebar with some product categories. As u can see there is same icon for every category. What i need is to change the icons so they will be all different.

I ll be gratefull for every help or advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a background of category listing li. it will change using css.